# How do I Use a variable multiple times in different functions

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to make a tip calculator, this takes in the total cost of the meal a tip (through a button) and the total amount of people. Although when I am attempting to get the value of the button to do my calculation I am unable to do so.

I have tried to just run the function on load although that only gives me the value of the button once when the page loads and not when it has been clicked.

What I am trying to do is know when the button has been pressed, take the value from it and then use that for my further calculations although when attempting to do so the variable is undefined and I can not use it in my main calculations function.

How would I go about solving this?

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7f4spx3/1/)

**HTML**

```
<h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
<div class="inputs">
  <input type="number" id="bill-amount" placeholder="Bill">
  <div id="buttons">
    <button value="5" class="btn">5%</button>
    <button value="10" class="btn">10%</button>
    <button value="15" class="btn">15%</button>
    <button value="20" class="btn">20%</button>
    <button value="30" class="btn">30%</button>
  </div>
  <input type="number" id="people-amount" placeholder="# Of people" onkeyup="tipCalculator()">
</div>
```

JS

```
$("button").click(function() {
   var buttonValue = $(this).val();
   console.log(buttonValue);
});

function tipCalculator() {
   var billAmount = $("#bill-amount").val();
   var peopleAmount = $("#people-amount").val();
   var total = (billAmount * buttonValue) / peopleAmount;
   total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
   total = total.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Just call your tipCalculator function from inside your click event

Comment: @CalebH. I did this before and it does not work? I added `tipCalculator();` after my console.log

Comment: you need to pass the value as a parameter to your `tipCalculator` function. Thats what Caleb meant

Comment: You aren't logging the value of your "total" variable anywhere, so you won't see any output

Comment: var buttonValue = document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[0].attributes[0].value;

...did you try to access with ".value" instead of ".val()" ?

Comment: @yBrodsky yes, thank you for clarifying

Comment: `var total .. total = total.toFixed(2);` - so the value is assigned to the *local variable* which is *"discarded"* when the function ends. Perhaps the computed value should be *used* (ie. update HTML) or *returned* so that is can be *used*? To persist a value between function calls it must be stored in a *global variable*, a variable *in a closure*, or a *property* (on an object with the same rules); or the *value must be stashed*, such as in a data-attribute or HTML update.

Comment: @JacquesAndre - danielarend's answer solved your problem and you've accepted it, but where he says "You should use a global var" I'd say "You _can_ use a global var" ... because you really _should *not*_ use a global var.  The `tipCalculator` should be passed _parameters_ and return the tip amount (or, arguably, the total w/tip) more in the way that jamesjaya's answer is laid out. If you're new to programming, you'll discover the [horrors of globals](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) soon enough. (but I wouldn't go so far as to say _never_ use them)

Comment: @StephenP thank you for the insight, I am new to programming so I haven't came across the problems of global variables yet, but I will be sure to keep it in mind!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use a global var, and then you can read it all the time. Just declare it out of your function and is done:

```
var buttonValue;

$("button").click(function() {
   buttonValue= $(this).val();
  console.log(buttonValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it in button click listener. Make tipCalculator receive one param and pass buttonValue value.

```
function tipCalculator(buttonValue) {
   var billAmount = $("#bill-amount").val();
   var peopleAmount = $("#people-amount").val();
   var total = (billAmount * buttonValue) / peopleAmount;
   total = Math.round(total * 100);
   total = total.toFixed(2);
   alert(total);
}

$("button").click(function() {
   var buttonValue = $(this).val();
   console.log(buttonValue);
   tipCalculator(buttonValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion `button` is the wrong element for this. It does not maintain state and it does not show your users what they have selected. Use radio buttons instead. This is even more important should the data be send back to a server for processing at any-point as the selected tip value would be lost without persisting it into another form field.

```js
function tipCalculator() {
  var billAmount = $("#bill-amount").val();
  var peopleAmount = $("#people-amount").val();
  //Get the tip value
  var tip = $("[name=rdoTip]:checked").val();  
  tip = (tip/100) + 1;
  console.log("Tip: " + tip);
  var total = (billAmount * tip) / peopleAmount;
  
  total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100 * 2;
  total = total.toFixed(2);
  console.log(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
<div class="inputs">
  <input type="number" id="bill-amount" placeholder="Bill">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Tip</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="rdoTip" value="0" id="rdoTip0" checked /><label for="rdoTip0">0%</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rdoTip" value="5" id="rdoTip5" /><label for="rdoTip5">5%</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rdoTip" value="10" id="rdoTip10" /><label for="rdoTip10">10%</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rdoTip" value="15" id="rdoTip15" /><label for="rdoTip15">15%</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rdoTip" value="20" id="rdoTip20" /><label for="rdoTip20">20%</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rdoTip" value="30" id="rdoTip30" /><label for="rdoTip30">30%</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<input type="number" id="people-amount" placeholder="# Of people" onkeyup="tipCalculator()">
```

You can make this a little prettier using CSS

```js
function tipCalculator() {
  var billAmount = $("#bill-amount").val();
  var peopleAmount = $("#people-amount").val();
  //Get the tip value
  var tip = $("[name=rdoTip]:checked").val();  
  tip = (tip/100) + 1;
  console.log("Tip: " + tip);
  var total = (billAmount * tip) / peopleAmount;
  
  total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100 * 2;
  total = total.toFixed(2);
  console.log(total);
}
```

```css
fieldset.tips {border:none; padding-left:0; margin-top:5px;}
fieldset.tips  legend {margin-left:0;}
fieldset.tips input[type="radio"] {display:none}
fieldset.tips label{padding:5px; border: solid red 1px; margin: 0 2px; border-radius: 5px; width: 40px; display:inline-block; text-align:center;}
fieldset.tips input:checked + label {background-color:red; font-weight:bold; color: #FFF;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
<div class="inputs">
  <input type="number" id="bill-amount" placeholder="Bill">
  <fieldset class="tips">
    <legend>Tip</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="rdoTip" value="0" id="rdoTip0" checked /><label for="rdoTip0">0%</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rdoTip" value="5" id="rdoTip5" /><label for="rdoTip5">5%</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rdoTip" value="10" id="rdoTip10" /><label for="rdoTip10">10%</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rdoTip" value="15" id="rdoTip15" /><label for="rdoTip15">15%</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rdoTip" value="20" id="rdoTip20" /><label for="rdoTip20">20%</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rdoTip" value="30" id="rdoTip30" /><label for="rdoTip30">30%</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<input type="number" id="people-amount" placeholder="# Of people" onkeyup="tipCalculator()">
```